# UI Testing Tool on linux

Tags: django, testing, automated-tests

Looking for a tool to UI testing on Linux .Platform used for development is django. 
The idea is that the analysts will capture the tests thru some UI and it will be able to be played back over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Selenium IDE, http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/